# How to return an image in fastAPI

Tags: python, api, opencv, opencv3.1, fastapi

I am trying to return an image in fastAPI after comparing two images using Opencv.

Here's what I have done so far:

```
from fastapi import FastAPI , File, UploadFile
import numpy as np
from cv2 import *
import os
import base64


app = FastAPI(debug = True)


@app.post("/uploadfile/")
async def create_upload_file(file: UploadFile = File(...),file1: UploadFile = File(...)):
    content = await file.read()
    nparr = np.fromstring(content, np.uint8)
    img = cv2.imdecode(nparr, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)

    content1 = await file1.read()
    nparr1 = np.fromstring(content1, np.uint8)
    img1 = cv2.imdecode(nparr1, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)

    akaze = cv2.AKAZE_create()
    kpts1, desc1 = akaze.detectAndCompute(img, None)
    kpts2, desc2 = akaze.detectAndCompute(img1, None)
    matcher = cv2.DescriptorMatcher_create(cv2.DescriptorMatcher_BRUTEFORCE_HAMMING)
    matches_1 = matcher.knnMatch(desc1, desc2, 2)
    good_points = []
    for m,n in matches_1:
            if m.distance < 0.7 * n.distance:
                good_points.append(m)
    mat = (round(len(kpts2)/len(good_points),2))
```

## where I am getting an error

```
    return_img = cv2.processImage(img)
    _, encoded_img = cv2.imencode('.PNG', return_img)
    encoded_img = base64.b64encode(return_img)

    return {"The similarity is": mat,'encoded_img': endcoded_img}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you mind pasting the requirements?

Comment: @MarceloTrylesinski , I want to return an image using fastapi , is that possible?

Comment: Does [How do I return an image in fastAPI?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55873174/3744182) answer your question?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I return an image in fastAPI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55873174/how-do-i-return-an-image-in-fastapi)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Yes you can return an image with FastAPI, it's actually so simple.

```
from fastapi import FastAPI
from fastapi.responses import FileResponse

some_file_path = "some_image.jpeg"
app = FastAPI()


@app.get("/")
async def main():
    return FileResponse(some_file_path)
```

Make sure to install `aiofiles` with `pip install aiofiles` otherwise, you'll be getting an error like this:

```
AssertionError: 'aiofiles' must be installed to use FileResponse
```

If you have an image as bytes consider using `StreamingResponse`

```py
from io import BytesIO

@app.post("/send_image")
async def send():
    image = BytesIO()
    img =                                        # Do something here to create an image
    img.save(image, format='JPEG', quality=85)   # Save image to BytesIO
    image.seek(0)                                # Return cursor to starting point
    return StreamingResponse(image.read(), media_type="image/jpeg")
```

Comment: i did install aiofiles, but still getting the same error

Answer (score 2):

The solution can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61345230/10617438). You are converting the Opencv Image before encoding it in the 3rd line.

```
    return_img = cv2.processImage(img)
    _, encoded_img = cv2.imencode('.PNG', return_img)
    encoded_img = base64.b64encode(return_img)

    return {"The similarity is": mat,'encoded_img': endcoded_img}
```

Replace `return_img` with `encoded_img` and everything should be working as expected.

```
    return_img = cv2.processImage(img)
    _, encoded_img = cv2.imencode('.PNG', return_img)
    encoded_img = base64.b64encode(encoded_img)

    return {"The similarity is": mat,'encoded_img': endcoded_img}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to return the image only, then return the image itself with the correct encoding in the header see [Return a Response Directly](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/response-directly/#returning-a-custom-response)

If you need to also return other information with the image in the json, then see this SO question [How do you put an image file in a json object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34485420/how-do-you-put-an-image-file-in-a-json-object) (note: the solutions are in javascript, but it's quite easy to adapt it for python)