# how to upload and download images in fastapi

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, fastapi

I'm developing a web application based on FastAPI and I need functionality for the user to upload an image. I want to save the downloaded image in a database so that I can access it in the future. How can I implement this functionality?

Concrete questions:

1. How to properly configure FastAPI for downloading files?
2. How to access the downloaded file and save it to the database?
3. What types of database fields should I use to store images?
4. What standard libraries or third party packages can make this process easier?

I've already looked at the FastAPI documentation and gone through various examples, but I haven't found complete information about loading images and storing them in the database. I would appreciate any help or code examples to help me figure this out.

Comment: Does this link help? https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/request-files/ Also this too https://saurabhchodvadiya.hashnode.dev/building-a-file-upload-and-download-api-with-python-and-fastapi

Answer (score 0):

> How to properly configure FastAPI for downloading files?

I have no idea what you mean by "properly configure". FastAPI has built in functionality to do this. A quick google search reveals [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62359413/how-to-return-an-image-in-fastapi) and [this](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/request-files/).

> How to access the downloaded file and save it to the database?

For purposes of demonstration, I'm gonna assume you're using postgres.

```
from fastapi import FastAPI, File, UploadFile
import psycopg2

app = FastAPI()
conn = psycopg2.connect("<conn string here>")

@app.route('/uploadfile')
async def create_upload_file(file: UploadFile):
    data = await file.read()
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute('INSERT INTO images (filename, filedata) VALUES (%s, %s)', (file.filename, data)) # filename is type text, filedata is type bytea
```

> What types of database fields should I use to store images?

`bytea` in Postgres. See [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-binary.html)

> What standard libraries or third party packages can make this process easier?

You really don't need much more than a library to interface with the database and FastAPI.